# Trying to set up static IP on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS install

Tags: networking, 18.04

The IPv4 configuration editor tells me the error message:

```
'192.168.1.2' is not contained in '255.255.255.0/24'
```

I tried to set the following values:

```
Subnet:      255.255.255.0/24
Address:     192.168.1.2
Gateway:     192.168.1.1
```

What am I doing wrong here?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My friend told me "you're confusing netmask and ADDR/PREFIX notation. 192.168.1.0/24 is what you want" which solved the problem

Comment: Ubuntu's installer made by real freaks

Comment: Thanks, I just need to find out what the other error is.